# How to check if a request is taking too long in requests?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

If I make a blocking request using `requests` to a remote api it takes too long then my site will return an error too.  I don't want that to happen.

This is the blocking code I have:

```
@app.route('/api')
def returnapi():
    r = requests.get("http://dndchecker.railsroot.com/api?mobile_number=9876543210")
    return r.text
```

I want to set the `r` value to False if the request object.

Comment: Well, what should happen instead if the server takes too long to respond?

Comment: @MartijnPieters For the questions sake lets say I want to return a string "Server taking too long. Try again." Or if possible I want the request to happen asynchronously and retrieved though Jquery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you could do this:

```
@app.route('/api')
def returnapi():
    try:
        r = requests.get("http://dndchecker.railsroot.com/api?mobile_number=9876543210", timeout=my_timeout)
    except (requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as err:
        return 'Server taking too long. Try again later'
    else:
        return r.text
```

That should help you prevent the server from taking too long. You of course have to define `my_timeout` to be the maximum you'd like to wait. I would caution you that you shouldn't set it too low though otherwise you'll always see the "Server taking too long. Try again later." The right amount of time is totally up to you as a service author and how long you feel is reasonable to wait.

Comment: thank you sir, I was unaware of this argument